# Validate uploaded file extension product save in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, file-upload

I have created a product attribute input type as 'file'.

**Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data\AddProductPdfProductAttribute.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data;
public function apply()
{
    $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
    /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'attachment',
        [
            'group' => 'Product Attachment',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Attachment',
            'input' => 'file',
            'backend' => 'X247commerce\Productpdf\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\File',
            'frontend' => '',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => '',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => 'simple,grouped,bundle,configurable,virtual', // applicable for simple and configurable product
            'used_in_product_listing' => true
        ]
    );

    $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
}
```

**Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\File.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\AbstractBackend;

class File extends AbstractBackend
{
protected $_file;
protected $_logger;
protected $_filesystem;
protected $_fileUploaderFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File $file,
    \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory
) {
    $this->_file = $file;
    $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
    $this->_fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
    $this->_logger = $logger;
}

public function afterSave($object)
{

    $path = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(
        DirectoryList::MEDIA
    )->getAbsolutePath(
        'catalog/product/attachment/'
    );
    $delete = $object->getData($this->getAttribute()->getName() . '_delete');

    if ($delete) {
        $fileName = $object->getData($this->getAttribute()->getName());
        $object->setData($this->getAttribute()->getName(), '');
        $this->getAttribute()->getEntity()->saveAttribute($object, $this->getAttribute()->getName());
        if ($this->_file->isExists($path.$fileName))  {
            $this->_file->deleteFile($path.$fileName);
        }

    }

    if (empty($_FILES['product']['tmp_name'][$this->getAttribute()->getName()])) {
        return $this;
    }

    try {
        /** @var $uploader \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader */
        $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'product['.$this->getAttribute()->getName().']']);
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['pdf']);
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $result = $uploader->save($path);
        $object->setData($this->getAttribute()->getName(), $result['file']);
        $this->getAttribute()->getEntity()->saveAttribute($object, $this->getAttribute()->getName());
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() != \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader::TMP_NAME_EMPTY) {
            $this->_logger->critical($e);
        }
    }

    return $this;
  }
}
```

From the above code I am able to upload and save the pdf file, but if I upload any other file still the product is getting saved.

Can we show some error message as **"only Pdf format is supported"**.

please someone help me to resolve this issue. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this below code before **afterSave()** function in your **File.php** file :

```
public function beforeSave($object)
{
    if ($_FILES['product']['type']['attachment'] != "application/pdf") {
        throw new LocalizedException(__('only Pdf format is supported'));
    }
    return parent::beforeSave($object);
}
```

Also, add this below class in your file :

```
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
```

Comment: hi @Rohan "Direct use of $_FILES Superglobal detected", can't use this

Comment: Try to get value from param : $files = $this->getRequest()->getFiles();